# Run VB Code Inside PowerShell

Tags: vba, powershell

Is it possible to run VB Code *inside* PowerShell?  I don't want to invoke a .vbs from inside PowerShell, I want to embed the VB code inside the PowerShell script.  I'm like, 90% sure you can do that, but I don't know how and can't seem to get a solid Google result.  I'm just guessing at this point.

I am currently invoking a .vbs with arguments inside PowerShell because the argument parameters are based on a selection the executer makes while running PowerShell, but I'd really like to wrap it all up into one file.

Currently, I am using this to turn page 2 of an Excel sheet into a CSV:

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Dim oBook
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
oBook.Worksheets(2).Activate
oBook.SaveAs WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6
oBook.Close False
oExcel.Quit
```

I tried to use [this from the Scripting Guy blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/03/22/how-can-i-save-a-single-excel-worksheet-to-a-csv-file/) but couldn't get it to work and never got an answer there.

I get this error:

```
Const : The term 'Const' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Const xlCSV = 6
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Const:String) [],     CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If anyone can show me how this PowerShell code would work to get the second sheet of my Excel sheet (SHEET1) I'd love that too.

I hope the answer is as simple and dumb as I think it is.  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Would help to include the relevant Powershell lines also

Comment: Your code snippet is a VBScript.  It appears that your PowerShell script needs to be provided, as that is indicative of PowerShell indicating an unexpected term.  And no, you can't "*write VB script inside PowerShell*" you'd have to invoke it, and pass data back and forth... but that seems very unnecessary.  Just use PowerShell.

Comment: My PowerShell code is fine.  The only reference to the .vbs within that is vb argument/invocation `.\Converter.vbs "$Selection" "$WorkCSV"`.  If anyone knows how to get that Scripting Guy part to work though, that would resolve my issue.

Comment: There's no need to use VBS when you could do this directly in Powershell itself:  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel/

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for that.  I'm looking at that but I'm not sure how I call my specific Excel file with that.  I get how it turns to the specified sheet and saves, but I'm not sure how I load my Excel document into that.

Comment: See my answer below - has hard-coded paths but if you have variables with "in" and "out" paths you would just use those instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to use VBS when you could do this directly in Powershell itself:

```
$a = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$a.Visible = $True

$b = $a.Workbooks.Open("C:\_Stuff\test2.xlsx")
$c = $b.Worksheets.Item(2)
$c.Activate()
$b.SaveAs(“C:\_Stuff\Test.csv”,6)
$b.Close(0)
$a.Quit()
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel/